# how can I write an android generic sharePref utils class?

Tags: java, android

I want to create a infrastructure utils class

but i don't know how to compare T to different types

i mean T == String, T == Object, T == Integer

(switch didn't work in Java below 1.7 and I'm not sure which java i can use on android 3 and above)

```
public T get<T>(String key) {


        if (T String.class))
        {
            return  prefs.getString(key, "");
        }
        else if ()
        {

        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "compare to different types"? Do you mean `<T extends SomeClass>`?

Comment: i mean T == String, T == Object, T == Integer

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misusing generics then. If T is going to be completely different subtypes you should attempt something along the lines of either an interface or just write separate methods entirely.

One thought on a solution that does come to mind:

```
Map<Object, String> yourPrefs;

public String get(Object key) {
    yourPrefs.get(key);
}
```

Most of those classes you are suggesting all implement `.equals()` and `.hashCode()`, so you should be fine in that regard.

Comment: The point of generics is more or less to avoid excessive type-checking and casting. Using a generic and then type-checking for numerous classes is no different than passing an `Object` instead. Unbounded generics are essentially Objects in the first place